# Pine Script: How to do a basic trade based on previous buy price

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am struggling to figure out how to get the previous buy price to play with like below. Please this is a basic trade, could you help me? thanks in advance:

This doesn't work, I dont get any error but the sell price is not 1% of previous buy price:

```
lastBuy = 0.0
longCondition = ppo < -0.07 and lastBuy == 0.0
if (longCondition)
    lastBuy := close[0]
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)
    

if (lastBuy * 1.01 < close[0])
    lastBuy := 0.0
    strategy.entry("SELL ", strategy.short)
```

Comment: Please provide a full working script to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reset `lastBuy` variable on every new iteration of the script, use the `var` [keyword](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html?highlight=var#variable-declaration) to initialize it as `0.0` only once per script load and then only reassign the value under `if` statements as in the example below:

```
var lastBuy = 0.0
longCondition = ppo < -0.07 and lastBuy == 0.0
if (longCondition)
    lastBuy := close[0]
    strategy.entry("BUY", strategy.long)
    

if (lastBuy * 1.01 < close[0])
    lastBuy := 0.0
    strategy.entry("SELL ", strategy.short)

// debug
// plot(lastBuy != 0 ? lastBuy : na)
plot(lastBuy)
```